# Why Stream<T> collect method returns different key order?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have this code:

```
public enum Continent {ASIA, EUROPE}

public class Country {      
   private String name;
   private Continent region;

    public Country (String na, Continent reg) { 
        this.name = na;
        this.region = reg;
    }
    public String getName () {return name;} 
    public Continent getRegion () {return region;}
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Country [name=" + name + ", region=" + region + "]";
    }
}
```

and in main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<Country> couList = Arrays.asList(
            new Country ("Japan", Continent.ASIA), 
            new Country ("Sweden", Continent.EUROPE), 
            new Country ("Norway", Continent.EUROPE));
        Map<Continent, List<String>> regionNames = couList
                .stream()
                //.peek(System.out::println)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Country::getRegion, Collectors.mapping(Country::getName, Collectors.toList())));
        System.out.println(regionNames);
}
```

If I run this code, I get this output:

```
{EUROPE=[Sweden, Norway], ASIA=[Japan]}
```

but if I uncomment the `peek` function, I get this output:

```
Country [name=Japan, region=ASIA]
Country [name=Sweden, region=EUROPE]
Country [name=Norway, region=EUROPE]
{ASIA=[Japan], EUROPE=[Sweden, Norway]}
```

My question is, can anybody tell me, why the keys order differs in the map `regionNames` when the `peek` function is in place?

Comment: This should really include a `hashCode` and `equals` for `Country` for correctness, but adding them doesn't seem to affect the problem.

Comment: Yes, I agree about `hashcode` and `equals`.

Comment: My mistake, you're using `Continent` as a key, no need for `hashCode` and `equals`.

Comment: Yes :) If I would be using `Continent` as a key, when I would need these methods. However, it doesn't matter. It doesn't solve this major problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `enum` implementation of `hashCode` uses the default one supplied by `Object`. [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) of that method mentions:

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. **This integer need *not* remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.**

Since the hash code is what determines the order of the buckets inside a `HashMap` (which is what `groupingBy` uses), the order changes when the hash code changes. How this hash code is generate is an implementation detail of the VM (as pointed out by Eugene). By commenting, and un-commenting the line with `peek`, you have simply found a way to influence (reliably or not) this implementation.

---

Since this question got a bounty, it seems like people are not satisfied with my answer. I will go a little bit more in depth and look at the **open-jdk8 implementation** (because it's open source) of `hashCode`. **DISCLAIMER: I will state again that the implementation of the identity hash code algorithm is not specified, and can be completely different for a different VM or between different versions of the same VM.** Since OP is observing this behaviour, I'll assume that the VM he is using is Hotspot (the Oracle one, which afaik uses the same hashcode implementation as opendjk). But **the main point in doing this is to show that commenting or un-commenting a seemingly unrelated line of code *can*  change the order of buckets in a `HashMap`.** This is also one of the reasons why you should ***never*** rely on the iteration order of a collection that does not specify one (like `HashMap`).

Now, the actual hashing algorithm for openjdk8 is defined in `synchronizer.cpp`:

```
 // Marsaglia's xor-shift scheme with thread-specific state
 // This is probably the best overall implementation -- we'll
 // likely make this the default in future releases.
 unsigned t = Self->_hashStateX ;
 t ^= (t << 11) ;
 Self->_hashStateX = Self->_hashStateY ;
 Self->_hashStateY = Self->_hashStateZ ;
 Self->_hashStateZ = Self->_hashStateW ;
 unsigned v = Self->_hashStateW ;
 v = (v ^ (v >> 19)) ^ (t ^ (t >> 8)) ;
 Self->_hashStateW = v ;
 value = v ;
```

As you can see, the hash code is based on these `_hashState` fields of the `Thread` object, and the output changes from one call to the next, since the variable values are 'shuffled'.

These variables are initialized in the `Thread` constructor like so:

```
_hashStateX = os::random() ;
_hashStateY = 842502087 ;
_hashStateZ = 0x8767 ;    // (int)(3579807591LL & 0xffff) ;
_hashStateW = 273326509 ;
```

The only moving part here is `os::random`, which is defined in `os.cpp` which has a comment describing the algorithm as:

```
next_rand = (16807*seed) mod (2**31-1)
```

This `seed` is the only moving part, and it is defined by `_rand_seed`, and initialized through a function called `init_random`, and at the end of the function, the returned value is used as a seed for the next call. A `grep` through the repo shows this:

```
PS $> grep -r init_random
os/bsd/vm/os_bsd.cpp:  init_random(1234567);
os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp:  init_random(1234567);
os/solaris/vm/os_solaris.cpp:  init_random(1234567);
os/windows/vm/os_windows.cpp:  init_random(1234567);
... test methods
```

It looks like the initial seed is a constant on the platform I'm testing (windows).

---

From that, I come to the conclusion that a generated identity hash code (in openjdk-8), changes based on how many identity hash codes have been generated on the same thread before it and by how many times `os::random` was called before the thread generating the hash code was instantiated, which stays the same for the example program. We can already kind of see this because the order of the keys doesn't change from run to run of the program, if the program stays the same. But another way to see it, is to put `System.out.println(new Object().hashCode());` at the beginning of the `main` method, and see that the output is always the same if you run the program a few times.

You will also notice that generating identity hash codes before the stream calls will also change the hash codes of the enum constants, and thus *can* change the order of the buckets in the map.

Now, let's go back to the Java example. If the identity hash code of an enum constant changes based on how many identity  hash codes have been generated before it, the logical conclusion would be that somewhere in the call to `peek`, an identity hash code is generated, which changes the hash codes that are generated for the enum constant on the line with `collect` afterwards:

```
Map<Continent, List<String>> regionNames = couList
        .stream()
        //.peek(System.out::println) // Does this call Object.hashCode?
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Country::getRegion,
            Collectors.mapping(Country::getName, Collectors.toList()))); // hash code for constant generated here
```

You can see this with an ordinary Java debugger. I've placed a breakpoint on `Object#hashCode`, and waited to see if the line with `peek` calls it. (If you try this yourself, I would note that the VM uses `HashMap` itself, and will call `hashCode` a number of times before the `main` method. So be aware of that)

Et voila:

```
Object.hashCode() line: not available [native method]   
HashMap<K,V>.hash(Object) line: 338 
HashMap<K,V>.put(K, V) line: 611    
HashSet<E>.add(E) line: 219 
Collections$SynchronizedSet<E>(Collections$SynchronizedCollection<E>).add(E) line: 2035 
Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).checkPackageAccess(Class<?>, ProtectionDomain) line: 508   
Main.main(String...) line: 19
```

The line with `peek` calls `hashCode` on a `ProtectionDomain` object that's used by the class loader that loads the `LambdaMetafactory` class (which is the `Class<?>` that you see, I can get the value from my debugger). The `hashCode` method is actually called a bunch of times (maybe a few hundred?), for the line with `peek`, throughout the MethodHandle framework.

So, since the line with `peek`, calls `Object#hashCode`, before the hash codes for the enum constants are generated (also by calling `Object#hashCode`), the hash codes of the constants change. So adding or removing the line with `peek` changes the hash codes of the constants, which changes the order of the buckets in the map.

One final way to confirm, is to generate the hash codes of the constants *before*  the line with `peek`, by adding:

```
Continent.ASIA.hashCode();
Continent.EUROPE.hashCode();
```

To the beginning of the `main` method.

You will now see that commenting or un-commenting the line with `peek` has no effect on the order of the buckets.

Comment: `since the hash code is based on where the object is in memory` not true. there are different hashcode strategies and in jdk-8 the default is Marsaglia-XOR-Shift, which is *not* using the place where the object exist in memory.

Comment: @Eugene Hmm, thanks. At the very least I was able to determine that the hash code for these objects can change (I thought based on memory usage). I will edit the answer.

Comment: According to the answer, I should create a wrapper class for these `enums` with my own implementation of `hashcode` which would act as a key in a map. Am I right?

Comment: @polis That would work I guess, but you really shouldn't rely on the iteration order of a stream, since it's undefined. If you need a certain ordering I would suggest using a [SortedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html).

Comment: @polis You should really not rely on the iteration order of `HashMap` as there is no guarantee about it. For example, it changed in Java 8 – we had badly written unit tests that failed because of this. Use a `SortedMap` or a `LinkedHashMap` instead.

Comment: @DidierL, I do not rely on the order, I just gave an example how to ensure same 'hashcode' in both cases. I appreciate your concern.

Comment: @polis: but there is no point in creating reproducible hash codes, when hash based data structures still don’t guaranty a predictable order. The `HashMap`’s order might even change within the same JVM. If you want a reproducible order, you can use `Collectors.groupingBy(Country::getRegion, ()->new EnumMap<>(Continent.class), Collectors.mapping(Country::getName, Collectors.toList()))`, then you’ll always get the declaration order of the `enum` constants.

Comment: @JornVernee amazing I was ready to post close to the same EXACT logic and answer today and literally thought I already did - reading your answer. I will not put one more here, but I would recommend adding two things here. identity hashcode on 64-bit VM has 31 bits in the object header (as opposed to 32). And 2) objects that do not override hashcode can not be used in the biased-locking algorithm. So synchronizing on an enum instance can not give you biased locking for it.

Comment: @Eugene Thanks :) Where would you suggest I add those? tbh, I'm not sure that information is relevant here, since this is not necessarily a question about how hash codes work.

Comment: @JornVernee indeed... this might not be that relevant after all. ignore that